# 0 Rows of Data to Database After Derived Column via SSIS

Tags: python, sql, visual-studio, ssis, etl

I'm importing a CSV file and want to concatenate two columns--month number & year. I'm achieving this by using the Derived Column function but when I execute the flow, 0 rows of data are making its way through. Any ideas of what the problem might be?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the datatype of source columns and the SSIS expression in derived column transformation. Make sure the datatypes are compatible for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a data viewer set at the destination flow - Are you aware that you have to hit the play button which you can find at the top left of the data-viewer window which opens up, for the data to be able to flow to the destination